# Formatting the date sent out by an Angular form

Tags: angular, rest, date

I am creating a form that displays values obtained from a REST API.It is also editable so that the user can enter new values for these fields and submit it to another API that updates in the DB.
This is one of the fields in the html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="editChangeRequestForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
<mat-form-field class="col-8" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Date Identified </mat-label>
          <input
            id="identifiedDate" 
            formControlName="identifiedDate"
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="basicDatepicker2"
            value="{{ changeRequest?.identifiedDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="basicDatepicker2"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #basicDatepicker2> </mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

This is the code in my template that sets the values obtained from the REST API in the form.

```
populateForm() {
    let currentChangeRequest = this.changeRequest;

    this.editChangeRequestForm.patchValue(currentChangeRequest);
   this.editChangeRequestForm.get('identifiedDate').setValue(this.formatDate(currentChangeRequest.identifiedDate));
    
    this.editChangeRequestForm.get('closedDate').setValue(this.formatDate(currentChangeRequest.closedDate));

} //End: populateForm()
```

Using patchvalue and setValue alone did not cause the datepicker field in the form to display the date obtained from the API hence, I introduced this method formatDate(date):

```
private formatDate(date) {
    const d = new Date(date);
    let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    let day = '' + d.getDate();
    let dateTime = d.toISOString;
    const year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    const firstConcat = [year, month, day].join('-');
    console.log('firstConcat', firstConcat);
    return firstConcat;
  } //End:formatDate(date)
```

This is the portion of the template that saves the form:

```
save() {
    const changes: ChangeRequest = {
      ...this.changeRequest,
      ...this.editChangeRequestForm.value,
    };
    this.dialogRef.close(changes);
  } //End: save()
```

The problem begins when the form is sent out to the back end, the REST API that updates the database. The  JSON that is sent out sends the identifiedDate in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. However, the backend can only accept dates in this format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX' due to this there is an error in the backend.
Can someone tell me how I can format the date that is sent out to the backend in the format of'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX'? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right you need this

[toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

**My workaround:**

**1.** Change the data type of `identifiedDate` and `closedDate` to `any`.

**2.** At your service, where you are calling you API:

**First**, create a shallow copy of your `changeRequest` object like:

`const requestCopy = { ...this.changeRequest };`

**Then**, apply `formatDate` function to `identifiedDate` and `closedDate` properties of your copied or cloned `requestCopy` object like:

`requestCopy.identifiedDate = this.formatDate(requestCopy.identifiedDate);`

**Finally**, you can send request with `requestCopy` object.

Hope this works.